# Reference Array in Different Class Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

So I have this function, which gets and prints all the HealthKit step data from the past 24 hours, and saves it to an array:

```
func stepsInPastDay(completion: (Double, NSError?) -> () )
{
    var dayStepData = [Double]()
    for x in 1...24 {
        // The type of data we are requesting
        let type = HKSampleType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierStepCount)
        var hoursAgo = -1 * x
        var hoursSince = (-1 * x) + 1
        // Our search predicate which will fetch data from now until a day ago
        let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamplesWithStartDate(NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(.CalendarUnitHour, value: hoursAgo, toDate: NSDate(), options: nil), endDate: NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(.CalendarUnitHour, value: hoursSince, toDate: NSDate(), options: nil), options: .None)

        // The actual HealthKit Query which will fetch all of the steps and sub them up for us.
        let query = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: type, predicate: predicate, limit: 0, sortDescriptors: nil) { query, results, error in
            var steps: Double = 0


            if results?.count > 0
            {
                for result in results as! [HKQuantitySample]
                {
                    steps += result.quantity.doubleValueForUnit(HKUnit.countUnit())
                }
            }

            completion(steps, error)

            dayStepData.append(steps)
            if dayStepData.count > 23 {
                for item in dayStepData {
                    println(item)
                }
            }
        }

        self.healthKitStore.executeQuery(query)
        println(dayStepData.count)
    }
    println(dayStepData.count)
}
```

However, when I tried to access the array (dayStepData) in my AppDelegate file, with "HKManager.stepsInPastDay.dayStepData" (HKManager is the class), Xcode returns an error. Is there a way to get the array from my function?

Comment: Ever heard of "scope of variables", the array is only available inside your function. create an instance variable or use a return statement to get access to the data outside the function.

Answer (score 1):

This is OOP (Object-oriented-programmming) 101 stuff. You are saving your value to a local variable. Of course it isn't visible in your app delegate.

Put the function in a singleton class of some sort make the function return the array as the function result.

If you're putting app logic in your app delegate you're doing it wrong. Keep your app delegate small and lightweight. It should ONLY handle startup and other app delegate tasks. Put your app-specific logic in other modules.